# How to apply margin in Presentation Document using OpenXml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I wrote code to create Presentation Document using open-xml SDK. I follow this sample code. [MSDD Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name). Now i need to apply margin before starting my text. I've tried below code but didn't get expected result.

```
slidePart1.Slide = new Slide(
                new CommonSlideData(
                    new ShapeTree(
                        new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
                            new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
                            new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
                            new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
                        new GroupShapeProperties(new A.TransformGroup()),
                        new P.Shape(
                            new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                                new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Title 1" },
                                new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
                                new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape())),
                            new P.ShapeProperties(),
                            new P.TextBody(
                                new D.BodyProperties(),
                                new D.ListStyle(),
                                new A.Paragraph(new D.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US" }, new D.ParagraphProperties() { LeftMargin = 10 }),
                                //new A.Paragraph(new A.Run(new A.RunProperties() { Bold = true, Italic = true, Underline = D.TextUnderlineValues.Single }, new A.Text()
                                //{ Text = text })))))),
                                new A.Paragraph(textListWithStyle.ToArray()))))),
                new ColorMapOverride(new D.MasterColorMapping()));
```

My generated PPT File looks like:

[image]

No left margin applied but in code i applied 10 left margin.

Comment: The standard way to find out "How do I do this using Office Open XML" is: open the presentation with the problem. Fix it manually, as a user. Save to a different file name. Open the original file in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Use the Tool's Compare feature to open the manually corrected file. This will 1) show where the difference is in the Open XML and 2) generate the code necessary to create the second file from the original. That should give you the information you need.

Comment: @Cindy Meister, Sir, could you please help me about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114536/how-to-insert-audio-file-in-word-doc-using-openxml

Answer (score 0):

It seems not so easy to add an indented paragraph using Open XML SDK. With [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), this can be done like this:

```cs
// Create a new presentation.
using var presentation = new Presentation();

// Add a text box to the first slide.
var slide = presentation.Slides[0];
var rectangle = slide.Shapes.AddAutoShape(ShapeType.Rectangle, 20, 20, 200, 150);

// Create a new paragraph.
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Text = "Some text.";

// Set left margin for the paragraph.
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.MarginLeft = 10;

// Add the paragraph to the text box.
rectangle.TextFrame.Paragraphs.Add(paragraph);

// Save the presentation to PPTX format.
presentation.Save("example.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

This is a paid product, but you can get a temporary license to evaluate all features of this library. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.