# How to insert Audio file in Word doc Using OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to insert audio file in Word doc using OpenXml. I've implemented my code but no audio file added after executing my Code. I take help OPEN XML SDK Tool 2.5 also. Code seems okay, but no audio inserted.Below is my tried code:

```
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Emf);

using (var imageStream = new ExportUtils().GetBinaryDataStream())
{
    imagePart.FeedData(imageStream);
}

EmbeddedObjectPart embeddedObjectPart = mainPart.AddEmbeddedObjectPart("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject");
thumPath = GetMyFilePath(); //Audio file path

using (var objStream = new FileStream(thumPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    embeddedObjectPart.FeedData(objStream);
}

AddAudio(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), mainPart.GetIdOfPart(embeddedObjectPart), posX, posY);
```

**Audio Insertion Code**

```
private static void AddAudio(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string imgRelationshipId, string objRelationshipId, int x, int y)
{

        string style = string.Format("position: absolute; margin - left:{0}pt; margin - top:{1}pt; width: 75.5pt; height: 49pt; z - index:-251657216; mso - position - horizontal - relative:text; mso - position - vertical - relative:text", x, y);

        ow.EmbeddedObject embeddedObject = new ow.EmbeddedObject() { DxaOriginal = "1440", DyaOriginal = "1440", AnchorId = "6359C433" };

        V.Shape shape = new V.Shape() { Id = "_x0000_s1026", Style = style };

        V.ImageData imageData = new V.ImageData() { Title = "Voice", RelationshipId = imgRelationshipId };

        shape.Append(imageData);
        Ovml.OleObject oleObject = new Ovml.OleObject() { Type = Ovml.OleValues.Embed, ProgId = "Package", ShapeId = "_x0000_s1026", DrawAspect = Ovml.OleDrawAspectValues.Icon, ObjectId = "_1647627410", Id = objRelationshipId };

        embeddedObject.Append(shape);
        embeddedObject.Append(oleObject);

        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new ow.Paragraph(new ow.Run(embeddedObject)));
 }
```

My project: x64